# I want to display the date of 1 day ago of current day

Tags: shell

For every start my application it should take sysdate- 2 date. i created shell script for that. But during month ends im facing the problem. its not updating correctly.

My script

```
a1=`date +%d`
a1=`expr $a1 - 2`
b1=`date +%m-%Y`
rm LastTopupDate.txt
echo $a1-$b1 >> Date.txt
```

help me out from this problem.?

Comment: 2 days ago (the day before yesterday) or 1 day ago (yesterday)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU `date`, you can use

```
a1=$(date +%s)
b1=$(date +%m-%Y --date @$((a1-2*86400)))
```

Syntax for other implementations may be different, but the same idea applies: `a1` is the date represented as a UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since a fixed epoch), and `b1` is the date that occurs 2 days (86,400 seconds in a day) earlier.

GNU `date` also provides a nicer shortcut:

```
b1=$(date +%m-%Y --date '2 days ago')
```

Comment: up! for the last cmd. with gnu date `date -d'-2 day' +%m-%Y` works too.

Comment: Don't assume that every day has 86400 seconds.'

Comment: True, a leap second could cause a day to have 86401 seconds, but for output with only one-day resolution, I think there are very few specific times when an assumption of 86400 seconds will produce the wrong output.

Comment: @chepner Twice a year in many countries, there are either 82800 or 90000 seconds days. Far less negligible than the leap seconds which are anyway able to wreak havoc in some cases ( http://www.wired.com/2012/07/leap-second-glitch-explained/ )

Comment: I overlooked daylight savings; at work, I rarely convert from UTC to a local time, and then only for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the title question which is about yesterday's date, here is something that should work on systems which do not provide GNU date:

```
h=$(date +%H)
today=$(date +%d)

for i in -12 -6 +0 +6 +12; do
        gmth=$(TZ=UTC$i date +%H)
        gmttoday=$(TZ=UTC$i date +%d)
        if [ $gmttoday == $today ] && [ $gmth -gt 4 ]; then
                TZ=UTC$((i+24)) date +%d-%m-%Y
                break
        fi
done
```